# How to filter data by user in spring boot applcation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

I'm making a simple spring boot application and I want to incorporate filtering data by logged-in user or user session. But I don't know what is the best way to set up the application in a way that every user can access data specific to him. I have made the authentification and authorization part of the app.

Comment: read this authentication and authorization spring boot https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on that kind of application and I've done this by adding as argument`@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails` to method where you want to get `userId`. Then you can call: `Integer userId = userDetails.getUserId();`

So for example something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/demo")
public String showTemplate(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
    Integer userId = userDetails.getUserId();
    return "index";
}
```

And  then you can do with this `userId` whatever you want. For example, create method in repository `findByUserId`

Comment: This way i need to provide userId in request?

Comment: Im assuming you have some logic where u implement UserDetails interface. If u have you can create method where u call user id and then call that method. So yes, this is one way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented UserDetails. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, finally implemented this work so well.